# Is there anyway that I can use new line character \n in Dictionary labels without the extra backslash being added?

Tags: dictionary

Just trying to format a dictionary label using `\n` characters and when it is returned via API. The new line characters have been escaped with an extra backslash.
Is there any way I can turn this off for these labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is performed in Sitecore with the `<getTranslation>` pipeline.

Maybe you can add a processor like this:

```
public class RemoveEscapes
{
    public void Process(GetTranslationArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        if (args.HasResult)
        {
            args.Result = args.Result.Replace("\\n", "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And add a patch config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <getTranslation>
                <processor type="Example.Foundation.Pipelines.RemoveEscapes, Example.Foundation"
                           patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromCoreDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
            </getTranslation>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is not a tested solution. Maybe give it a try and change the code as required.